# How to put "rm -i" in an iteration?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, rm

```
echo "$MOUNTPOINTLIST" | while read onelinefortouch; do touch "${onelinefortouch}testfileforwrite"; done
echo "$MOUNTPOINTLIST" | while read onelineforrm; do rm -i "${onelineforrm}testfileforwrite"; done
```

**Question:** But this doesn't brings up the files one-by-one when the "rm -i" comes. Why? How to fix this?

Comment: Can you once try `-I` instead of `-i`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `rm -i` expects user's input from stdin, too.  Try this:

```
echo "$MOUNTPOINTLIST" | while read onelineforrm; do rm -i "${onelineforrm}testfileforwrite" < /dev/tty; done
```